# Intersection of sets containing $\omega$ is an atom.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that the intersection of all sets in a $\sigma$-Algebra $S$ which contain $\omega$, denoted as $E_\omega$, is an atom.

I have attempted a proof by contradiction and a direct proof, but I just don't see how to get the inclusion I need, I must be missing a key step.

To be honest, I don't even see why for $S\ni A\subseteq E_\omega$ the element $\omega$ needs to be in $A$, let alone all other elements of $E_\omega$.

Comment: As you say, it is not true in general, for instance for the trivial sigma-algebra that contains only $\emptyset$ and the whole set.

Comment: @Raoul to test for an Atom set, the set $A$ must be from the Sigma-Algebra, I'll edit for clarity. Thanks :)

Comment: What is $\omega$?